# Python: using user input. My code below is only able to strip one char from a string. And I need it to able to strip multiple characters

Tags: python, string

```
word = input("Enter a string/sentence: \n")
char = input("\nWhich characters would you like to make disappear? \n")
new_word = word.replace(char, "")
print("\n" + str(new_word))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check every character in the word and then use `str.join` to join non-removed characters together. For example:

```
word = input("Enter a string/sentence: \n")
chars = input("\nWhich characters would you like to make disappear? \n")
new_word = "".join(ch for ch in word if ch not in chars)    # <-- use str.join
print("\n" + str(new_word))
```

Prints:

```
Enter a string/sentence: 
abcabc

Which characters would you like to make disappear? 
ac

bb
```